# On the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the following series absolutely converge, conditionally converge or diverge?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)$$

My answer:
$$ 0<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\left|\frac{\cos(\pi n/2)}{n}\right| $$
and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges by p-series test so by comparison test, the original series must also diverge.

Comment: Sorry, no that is not the series i want. I'm still getting used to writing in this format.

Comment: I want the n to be 1/n and all that multiplied by the cosine

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you,!

Comment: Do u think my answer is right?

Comment: Your series is conditionally convergent by Dirichlet's test. The series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{|\cos(\pi n/2)|}{n}$ is divergent, of course, but your conclusion is incorrect.

Comment: We did not learn Dirichlet's test in the Math course I am currently enrolled in.

Comment: You can also check your series equals $-\frac{\log 2}{2}$.

Comment: Is there a way to do it from the following tests: limit comparison, comparison, integral test, alternating series test, divergence test, ratio, root test?

Comment: The alternating series test is a peculiar instance of Dirichlet's test and it perfectly works in this case. Your series is $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}-\ldots$

Comment: Ohhh yes i see it now, thank you very much Jack!

Answer (score 2):

This series is **conditionally convergent**. Its terms are:
$$\frac{1}{n}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{llll}
    \frac{1}{n} & \mbox{if } n=4k , k>0\\
   0 & \mbox{if } n=4k+1 , k\ge0\\
   -\frac{1}{n} & \mbox{if } n=4k+2 , k\ge0\\
   0& \mbox{if } n=4k+3, k\ge0\\
 \end{array}
\right. $$
By removing zero expression, and just considering $n=4k$ and $n=4k+2$, we could replace and change indices. By write some sentences for this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)=0-\frac{1}{2}+0+\frac{1}{4}+0-\frac{1}{6}+0+\frac{1}{8}+0+...=\\-\frac{1}{2}\Big(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...\Big)=-\frac{\ln{2}}{2}\approx-0.3466$$

---

It's conditionally convergences because 
$$\sum \left|\frac{\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{n}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\Big(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...\Big)$$
doesn't converge.

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: What's the problem? Please write it! I think it's correct.

Comment: I could use different index for each series.

Comment: We have 4 condition for $n$ in this equation. So I could remove $\cos$ and replace it with "$0,+1,-1$". Don't write $0$ , just write $+1,-1$

Comment: Please notice to the first equation in my solution

Comment: I corrected it! Thanks for  your attention. But please don't Threaten someones for decreasing credit in such sites. I consume my time to answer question freely just like You. Users could make another account and continue to their activities.

Comment: You wrote to me: ' fix it before the down-voters arrive ;)'
I just explained more and more details for preventing receive minus from users!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89531/discussion-between-barzanhayati-and-rtybase).

Comment: I updated your answer. Do you think it's more concise now, while keeping the overall idea intact?

Comment: Thanks. That's right.

Comment: I went through the conversations, and yes I learned something new!! thank you :) and I think mentioning a reference to the Quora post would be nice, as it is explained in a  concise way!!

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ any natural number, then
$$
2\sum^{M}_{n=1}\cos(n\pi/2)=-1+\cos(M\pi/2)+\sin(M\pi/2).
$$ 
Hence the partial sums of $\cos(n\pi/2)$ are bounded. Also $\frac{1}{n}$ is a null monotonic sequence. Hence from Dirichlet's test (see [1] pg. 315), the series
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\cos(n\pi/2)}{n}
$$ 
converges to a number. Moreover the series
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\cos(n x)}{n^a}\textrm{, }a>0
$$
converges in every interval of the form $\epsilon\leq x\leq 2\pi-\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ any number in $(0,\pi)$ (see [1] pg.349).

References.

[1]: Konrad Knopp. ''Theory and application of infinite series''. Dover. (1990)